# Getting wikimapia embeded in Leaflet map?

Tags: leaflet, point-of-interest, wikimapia

I have a leaflet map where I want to get wikimapia POI and data inside my map so I could identify some Points of interests and informations which are in wikimapia ,I have a wikimapia kml that loads in google maps, but How to have it in leaflet is this possible?

```
 <html>

<head>
  <title>
    POI
  </title>
  <meta http-equiv='content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://k2scc.onlinewebshop.net/plunkers/leaflet/leaflet.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://k2scc.onlinewebshop.net/plunkers/src/leaflet-search.css" />
  <style>
    html,
    body,
    #map {
      height: 100%;
    }

    body {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>

  <div id=map></div>
  <script src="http://k2scc.onlinewebshop.net/plunkers/leaflet/leaflet-src.js"></script>
  <script src='http://k2scc.onlinewebshop.net/plunkers/leaflet-omnivore/leaflet-omnivore.js'></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var Raster = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}', {
      subdomains: ['mt0', 'mt1', 'mt2', 'mt3'],
      minZoom: 8,
      maxZoom: 22,
      maxNativeZoom: 22
    });
    googleStreets = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=m&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}', {
      subdomains: ['mt0', 'mt1', 'mt2', 'mt3'],
      minZoom: 8,
      maxZoom: 22,
      maxNativeZoom: 22
    });

    var OSMR = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      minZoom: 8,
      maxZoom: 22,
      maxNativeZoom: 19
    });

    var map = L.map('map', {
      attributionControl: false,
      zoomControl: false
    }).setView([35.750719, 10.711866], 8).addLayer(googleStreets);

    L.control.layers({
      'Satelite': Raster,
      'OSM': OSMR,
      'Google map': googleStreets
    }).addTo(map);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

here my pluncker code:
http://plnkr.co/edit/FNUDToR2XmSO2rIaK9pw?p=preview

Comment: Have you checked Leaflet plugins (https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html) for KML plugin?

Comment: I used omnivore for loading kml but Wikimapia kml is not a normal kml it loads over network kind of WMS or something from remote

Comment: Can you share link to this service?

Comment: link: http://wikimapia.org/ge.kml

Comment: This KML just gives you link to http://wikimapia.org/d/, which gives you message `API next version will be available soon.` API is documented here: http://wikimapia.org/api/. To use it you need API key. For this you have to register at  http://wikimapia.org/#show=/user/login/

Comment: Can you do a demo changing my pluncker code I am beginner

Comment: I don't have API key, so I can't test it.

Comment: Application
    POI windows
Key
    844D13FD-58C54861-AFED8F14-DEE8043B-DB938F2D-EEF4E690-91F244A9-A9A1BE8E not verified 
Key limits
    Up to 100 requests in 5 minutes. 
    Key statistics Upgrade limit

Application
    POI windows
Key
    844D13FD-812664AA-A06C2896-2BB9A61D-75CF1175-CCE3CF8B-19B0A811-6E42D60D not verified 
Key limits
    Up to 100 requests in 5 minutes. 
    Key statistics Upgrade limit

Comment: I developped this tool (https://github.com/martinedoesgis/wikimapia-export) to export wikimapia in GeoJSON, you can export what you need and display them in leaflet using a new L.GeoJSON()